# Calling Laravel Seeder inside folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

I've upgraded to Laravel 8, but my custom seeder in a subdirectory is not working. The file is at `database/seeders/tests/TestSeeder.php.`

When I run the command `php artisan db:seed --class="TestSeeder"` it return an error message:

```
Target class [Database\Seeders\TestSeeder] does not exist.
```

**Seeder**

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders\Tests;

class TestSeeder extends BaseSeeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
       // codes
    }
}
```

**composer.json**

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\Tests\\": "database/seeders/tests/"
    }
},
```

Comment: you put `TestSeeder` in the `Database\Seeders\Tests` namespace

Comment: still not working.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Would it need to be --class='Tests\TestSeeder' in your command?

Comment: Still not working, btw, I'm currently upgrading my Lumen 5.8 to Lumen 8.x
then I saw that database/seeds renamed to database/seeders thats why I moved my seeder inside database/seeder folder.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Laravel assumes you are running a seeder from the `Database\Seeders\DatabaseSeeder` class. If you provide an unqualified class name such as `TestSeeder`, it will assume you mean the `Database\Seeders\TestSeeder` class.

So, you should specify the fully qualified class name.

```sh
php artisan db:seed --class="Database\\Seeders\\Tests\\TestSeeder"
```

Comment: Thank you @miken32. 
What's wrong in my app. when I run `php artisan make:seeder TestSeeder` it created inside `database/seeds` folder?

Comment: Ensure you've properly updated the versions of all packages in `composer.json` including `"laravel/framework": "^8.12"`

Comment: thanks bru, I just need to remove `/database/seeds` folder. and all works good, :)

Comment: Worth noting is that specifying even the relative path within the "default" folder structure doesn't work. Fully qualified in the this answer *really* does mean *fully qualified*. eg. `class=UserSeeders\\AdminUserSeeder` won't work even if the folder structure is `database\seeders\UserSeeders\AdminUserSeeder.php`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about the sub folder, no need to mention it in the command,

1. Just run the `composer dump-autoload`
2. Then run the `php artisan db:seed --class="TestSeeder"` command

This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

##### In addition for [@miken32 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65210414/13551566):

for me also worked

```bash
php artisan db:seed --class="Database\Seeders\Tests\TestSeeder"
```

Comment: Works fine until you have a folder name that starts with an n or a t. Always escape backslashes.

Comment: @miken32 maybe it will sound funny, but for me didn't worked your solution)))